# How do i get my resource controller to fire the destroy _method?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am having a problem with the laravel5 resource controller. The POST method is working fine however the delete method is not. as you can see from postman i am passing the DELETE _method to the correct route

[image: postman screen capture]
In the mean time i am using direct routes which are also working fine.

```
Route::delete('customisemymeal', ['as'=>'customisemymeal', 'uses'=>'UserMealCustomController@destroy']);
Route::post('customisemymeal', ['as'=>'customisemymeal', 'uses'=>'UserMealCustomController@store']);
```

I have disabled the CSRF token check until this is sorted out.

Can you please help explain why the same method is different for a resource controller compared to a `route::delete`?

routes:list

```
  | DELETE                         | customisemymeal/{customisemymeal}                                       | customisemymeal.destroy            | App\Http\Controllers\UserMealCustomController@destroy         |

     | DELETE                         | customisemymeal                                       | customisemymeal           | App\Http\Controllers\UserMealCustomController@destroy         |
```

Comment: I have abandoned using the resource. I believe the use of route model binding would be the best way forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the route:

```
Route::resource('customisemymeal', ['as'=>'customisemymeal', 'uses'=>'UserMealCustomController']);
```

You must abide to a few rules. To delete something you need to use:

```
domain.com/customisemymeal/resource_id
```

From your screenshots you are trying to delete a resource, using a different URI.

```
domain.com/customisemymeal
```

That won't work.

Rules are:

```
Index:
GET -> domain.com/resource

Show:
GET -> domain.com/resource/resource_id

create:
GET -> domain.com/resource/create

edit:
GET -> domain.com/resource/resource_id/edit

update:
PATCH / UPDATE -> domain.com/resource/resource_id

store:
POST -> domain.com/resource

delete:
DELETE -> domain.com/resource/resource_id
```